# I like little squares but not as much as TeXstudio

Tags: mac, texstudio

I recently downloaded TeXstudio and I really like it's feel, only problem:

[image: TeXstudio source page]

Gave it a quick google and nothing came up.

Has anyone else encountered this problem OR does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: The title is sweet. :-)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel an answer? :)

Comment: [+1] I really like the quasi-cynical mathematical phrasing of the question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the top bar of TeXstudio click  ***Options***   and then select  ***Configure TeXstudio***

select  ***Editor***   from the left list of the Configure TeXstudio window

The defaults should be:

> **Font Family:**    Courier New  **or**  possibly Monaco on a Mac
>
> **Default Font Encoding:**    UTF-8

If a different font is selected, the font may not have the necessary characters to properly display the text.

If the default font encoding is anything but UTF-8, chances are good this is your problem, because even if the font has all the characters they will still not be able to display because the wrong encoding is being used and all the characters needed are not available to the font for it to display them.